# Examples of Triangulated Categories that aren't quotient categories

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, triangulated-categories

My professor is introducing Triangulated Categories, and the examples given so far are:

- **K**(R) - the homotopy category of R-module complexes
- **D**(R)- the derived category of R-module complexes
- $\underline{\text{R-Mod}}$ - the stable category of R-modules
- **HMF**($S , x$) - the homotopy category of matrix factorizations
- Various triangulated subcategories of these as well

My question is this: are there examples of non-trivial triangulated categories that are not non-trivial quotient categories? If there are any, are they useful?

NOTE:
By "quotient categories", I mean categories that one constructs by taking quotienting out an equivalence relation on morphisms and non-trivial quotient categories are those which are categories that are quotiented with themselves.

Comment: What does it mean to be a quotient category? To be constructed by quotienting out an equivalence relation on morphisms? I would be surprised if your professor gave a construction of the derived category of unbounded complexes (as opposed to those which are bounded above or below) as a quotient in that sense-this is difficult. It's usually constructed as a localization.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I mean a quotient category to be a category that one quotients out an equivalence relation. My professor constructed the derived category by localizing the homotopy category, which is a quotient category. In that sense, the derived category is a localized quotient category.

Comment: Oh, well, the localization is a big deal! Every localization is a location of a quotient category in a trivial sense, and essentially every triangulated category, including every important one, is a localization of some kind. But that's an incredibly broad class.

Comment: Every category is a quotient of itself, so the question is trivial as stated.

Comment: @Hurkyl I edited the question in order to make it non-trvial in the aspect you mention.

Comment: Every category is also a quotient of the free category generated by its underlying graph. 99 times out of 100, if you have to put in ad-hoc conditions to exclude the obvious things, you're missing the point. I presume you have some ideas about what the category you're taking the quotient of should be -- what your question should do is *say what those things are*.